# python boto3 parameter validation error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Here I have written a python program to start an instance that matches all the conditions. But The following error is displayed while executing the program.`botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter InstanceIds, value: i-012345678, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>` .Below is my code:

```
import boto3
ec2=boto3.client('ec2',region_name='ap-south-1')
a=ec2.describe_instances()
for i in a['Reservations']:
    for x in i['Instances']:
       if x['InstanceId']=="i-12345678" and x['State'['Name']=='stopped':
            n = x['InstanceId']
            ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=n)`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error itself is self-explanatory. You have to pass a list or tuple of instance ids rather than just string. You can see this in the [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.start_instances)

See the updated code below.

```
import boto3
ec2=boto3.client('ec2',region_name='ap-south-1')
a=ec2.describe_instances()
for i in a['Reservations']:
    for x in i['Instances']:
       if x['InstanceId']=="i-12345678" and x['State'['Name']=='stopped':
            n = x['InstanceId']
            ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[n])`
```