# How to read Txt file from S3 Bucket using Python And Boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

How to read Txt file from S3 Bucket using Python And Boto3
I am using the below script which is working very well I am able to see instance name which is in the S3 bucket

```
import boto3
import codecs

access_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
secret_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxx"
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key, region_name='us-east-1')

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key, region_name='us-east-1')

bucket = 'stoppedinstanceidslist'
key = 'StoppedInstanceidsList.txt'
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
InstancetobeStart = (obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
ids=InstancetobeStart
print(type(ids))   # <class 'str'>
print(ids)  #  ['i-041fb789f1554b7d5', 'i-0d0c876682eef71ae']

response =ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=ids)

print("Your Instances are Started now which are stopped last day")
```

After using response I am getting the below error

```
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter InstanceIds, value: ['i-041fb789f1554b7d5', 'i-0d0c876682eef71ae'], type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
['i-041fb789f1554b7d5', 'i-0d0c876682eef71ae']
```

What to do in case that my program stop instances after reading from the s3 bucket

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python boto3 parameter validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298295/python-boto3-parameter-validation-error)

Comment: no actually Here I am reading from the S3 bucket file not from describe instance I already have a list of instance in my s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ids` is literal string `['i-041fb789f1554b7d5', 'i-0d0c876682eef71ae']`, not a list. To parse it and convert to list use [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module:

```
import ast
# ...
InstancetobeStart = (obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
ids = ast.literal_eval(InstancetobeStart)
```